# bash: cd: desktop/android: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, android, directory, cd-command

I am trying to flash 4.4.3 to my Nexus 5.

When I enter this

```
cd desktop/android
```

I get this:

```
bash: cd: desktop/android: No such file or directory
```

I am looking right at the folder on my desktop named `android`. I tried the same command with other folders and I get the same error. Can anyone tell me why or what I am doing wrong?

*Also*, here is [the guide I am following](http://www.cultofandroid.com/63876/install-android-4-4-3-nexus-5-nexus-4-nexus-7/).

Comment: use `Desktop` instead of `desktop`

Comment: Check your directory spell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command would be,

```
cd Desktop/android
```

OR

```
cd ~/Desktop/android
```

Please note that linux commands are case sensitive.

Comment: So desktop needs to be capitalized?  :O

Comment: only D from the desktop.

Comment: Thats crazy! Your the man though! I appreciate the fast and helpful responses. Lets see if I can flash it!!

Comment: Can you help me through this process? I have a few other questions and you seem like you know this pretty well.

Comment: which process? I'll try .

Comment: Flashing 4.4.3 to my nexus 5 w. a custom recovery. I send the command fastboot devices. and get this "dtmfool@dtmfool-Vostro-3400:~/Desktop/android$ flash-all.sh
flash-all.sh: command not found" Which I imagine means it did not find my nexus 5? Any idea why this issue is happening?

Comment: what the output of fastboot devices command. Is that it detects your device?

Comment: The output is "no permissions   fastboot"

Comment: Then run this command `sudo fastboot devices`

Comment: HOLY HEYSUES! WIN! yeah it spit back out the serial number! Okay I am going to continue onto the next steps! Thank you so much. I hope I dont run into any more problems.

Comment: I am now running 4.4.3! Your the man!

Comment: Once in the correct directory, the command is: **`./flash-all.sh`** If you don't add the prefix ('./') it will look for a script (or executable) in the directories listed in $PATH.

Comment: @user288254 Enjoy your new android 4.4.3 version :-)

Comment: I tried it without the ./ and it didnt go through so I tried it  like what and BOOM I am running 4.4.3.